# Nvidia Driver crashes compiz

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz

I've installed Nvidia driver from terminal with sudo apt-get install nvidia-current, and after that compiz crashes every time after I log in. Can someone tell me how to make it work?

My video card is Nvidia GT630M and I also have Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Maybe the problem is in Intel Graphic Card, I have the same problem with compiz but after 
installing the Intel Graphics Drivers, the problem gone. 
Try to install it :
1. Type in Terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) (without quotes)
"wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \sudo apt-key add -"

2. Go to this link and download drivers
```

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer

The problem has gone for me, just typed in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: LOL the problem with compiz return

Comment: The problem has gone (for me) just typed in terminal:
<b> sudo apt-get autoremove <\b>